# Appscript API for fetching access permissions of team drive

Tags: google-apps-script, google-app-maker

I am trying to generate a report of all access permissions currently various users have in Team Drive. Is there any API in Appscript to Fetch this data?

Comment: I don't believe team drives are supported in the DriveApp at this moment.

Comment: I can see Powertools providing this report, so is there any other way I can fetch this data?

Comment: @DarpanSanghavi yes, use the Drive API (i.e. the advanced service).

Comment: Can you please provide me a refn link for this use case? I am aware with DriveAPI but could not find any refn for fetching file access rights for Team Drive

Comment: You may want to check this https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/permissions/list

Comment: @AntonDementiev the Apps Script advanced service uses Drive v2, not v3

Comment: No need to use the advanced service - he could simply query the REST API endpoint by using UrlFetchApp - it adds another layer of complexity with authorization, but it should work.

Comment: @AntonDementiev :: This API provide me Permissions list but I am still not clear on what should I provide to receive file name, file access and username in response.

Comment: @tehhowch :: I've tried using Advanced service as well, I've enabled Drive SDK and query on a file but I am not getting anything in permissions value. As per doc it suggests I should use permissions.list method. But I am not sure how. If you can give me some insight that would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be any method for getting Drive permissions sorted by username, so you will need to implement this business logic yourself. According to the documentation, sending a GET request to the API endpoint below will get you the list of permissions for the Team Drive (use Team Drive ID instead of file id):

> https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/fileId/permissions

I don't have any Team Drives set up - the example below is based on getting permissions for a single file using Drive REST API. Before the code can be executed, you must prove your identity by including API key in URL parameters and passing OAuth token in the headers of your 'GET'request. 
The API key can be obtained from Google Cloud console. Enable the Drive API and click the key icon in the left menu to set up credentials. Choose "API key" from the drop-down and copy the value.

Your script must pass the token that includes all required authorization scopes to the API endpoint. OAuth scopes are set explicitly in the manifest file. In Script Editor, select "View - Show manifest file" and add relevant scopes.  Scopes used in my manifest file are for accessing Drive Files and calling external services via UrlFetchApp:

```
 "oauthScopes": [
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive",
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request"]
```

Finally, get the list of permissions for the file:

```
  var fileId = "FILE_ID";
    var apiKey = "API_KEY";

    var apiUrl = "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/fileId/permissions";

    var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
    var header = {"Authorization":"Bearer " + token};

    var options = {
    "method":"GET",
    "headers": header,
    "muteHttpExceptions": true
    };

    var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(apiUrl.replace("fileId", fileId) + "?key=" + apiKey, options)
                         .getContentText();

        var permissions = JSON.parse(res);
        Logger.log(permissions);
```

Comment: Any particular reason why you don't use the native client library / advanced service, and prefer instead UrlFetchApp?

Comment: The reason was the one you mentioned above - this method uses version 3 of Drive API that Advanced Drive doesn't seem to support https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/permissions/list   Maybe it does, but I have no idea if it supports passing Team Drive ids as well as file ids.

Comment: apps script uses v2 :)

Comment: Anton: I will try the solution and keep you updated. Appreciate the help.

Comment: Tehhowch : I have tried using advance service,but as I said Drive SDK does not return me any method which can give me permission in team drive. If you can provide me any method name/ snippet that will help.

Comment: @AntonDementiev : After doing some tweaks I was able to fetch file permissions. I will post my full code shortly here. Thanks much for the support!!

Answer (score 1):

Updates with help from **Anton's** answer. (Working with Appmaker as well).

Here's how I have achieved it,

```
function fileExport(folderId) //pass folder id or drive/team drive id to fetch permissions
{
    var parent = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
    var path = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId).getName();
    var fileName = 'Permisssions_' + new Date(); //define file name
    var newExport = SpreadsheetApp.create(fileName); // create new spreadsheet
    var header = ["Path","Folder","File Name","Email","Role","Name","DocUrl"]; //define header
    newExport.appendRow(header); // append header to spreadsheet
    newExport.setFrozenRows(1);
    newExport.getRange("A1:H1").setFontWeight("bold");

    //traverse through each folder under current folder
    getChildFolders(parent,newExport,path);

     //appned files associated with current folder
    var files = parent.getFiles();

    while (files.hasNext()) {
      var file = files.next();
      var permitFile=  makeRestCall(file.getId());  

      for(var j=0; j<permitFile.length;j++)
      {
          newExport.appendRow([path,'',file.getName(),permitFile[j].emailAddress, permitFile[j].role,permitFile[j].displayName,file.getUrl()]);
      }
     }
    return 'File exported successfully to this path:'+ newExport.getUrl(); 
}
//Iterate through child folders using recursive call
function getChildFolders(parent,newExport,path) {

  var childFolders = parent.getFolders();

  while (childFolders.hasNext()) {

    var childFolder = childFolders.next();
    path = path +'--'+childFolder.getName();
    var permit=  makeRestCall(childFolder.getId());
    for(var i=0; i<permit.length;i++)
    {
        newExport.appendRow([path,childFolder.getName(),'',permit[i].emailAddress, permit[i].role,permit[i].displayName,childFolder.getUrl()]);
    }

    var files = childFolder.getFiles();

    while (files.hasNext()) {
      var file = files.next();
      var permitFile=  makeRestCall(file.getId());  

      for(var j=0; j<permitFile.length;j++)
      {
          newExport.appendRow([path,'',file.getName(),permitFile[j].emailAddress, permitFile[j].role,permitFile[j].displayName,file.getUrl()]);
      }
    }
    // Recursive call for any sub-folders
    getChildFolders(childFolder,newExport,path);    
  }
}

function makeRestCall(fileOrFolderId)  //make rest call to fetch permissions
{
  var apiUrl = "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/fileId/permissions";

  var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
  var header = {"Authorization":"Bearer " + token};

  var options = {
    "method":"GET",
    "headers": header
  };
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(apiUrl.replace("fileId", fileOrFolderId) + "?supportsTeamDrives=true&fields=*", options)
  .getContentText();
  var dataAll = JSON.parse(response); 
  var permit = dataAll.permissions;
  return permit;
}
```